# How to auto fill search tab in following way?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

[image]

I have

```
class A(osv.osv):
      _name="A"
      _columns={
                'name':fields.char("Name"),}


   <field name="name"/>
   <button ="submit">
```

When i click button this name should autofill at following search box like name:'shridhar'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
<record id="view_serch_view_A" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Searchv View A</field>
            <field name="model">A</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Search">
                    <filter string="Shridhar" domain="[('name','=','shridhar')]" name="my_filter"/>
                </search>
            </field>
</record>


<record id="action_A" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Action A</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">A</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{
                'search_default_my_filter': 1
            }
        </field>
</record>
```

Hope this helps.